# Go to the next parameter Twig

Tags: loops, twig

I'm new on Twig and i would like to know how to go to the next value in a loop

This is a simple example:

```
{% for user in users %}
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
                {{ user.username }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {# here i want to print the next username in the same line of the table #}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
```

And thanks for your help
Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do

```
{{ user[loop.index + 1].username }}
```

There's some further information about the `loop` variable at http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

Comment: this is not an array, it's a result of a SELECT statement this didn't work for me !

Comment: @BaHarAyØub did you {{ users[loop.index + 1].username }} user'S' because you have to point the array not le local user

Comment: @BaHarAyØub a select statement result is either an array or an object - either way, it can be accessed as per my example

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check if the user is not the last one before displaying the next one

```
{% for user in users %}
<table>
     <tr>
          <td>
           {{ user.username }}
          </td>
          <td>
               {% if not loop.last%}
                    {{ users[loop.index0 + 1].username }}
               {%endif%}
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is what i get
Key "2" in object (with array access) of Type \Arkiglass\ProduitBundle\Entity\Produit does not exist in ArkiglassProduitBundle:Site:produit.html.twig at line: 43
the line 43 is the new instruction users[loop.index + 1].username
and im sure that user is not the last one before displaying the next one

Comment: How many produit do you have ? do you have getProduit() method witch return array in your user entity ?

Comment: @BaHarAyØub allso trie with loop.index0 to get the index from 0 and not from 1